# Jquery cookie save selection of multiple <select>

Tags: jquery, cookies, html-select

Seems like this has been asked multiple times in the past but the questions go unanswered for some reason.

I'm trying to save the selection of multiple  inputs. I'm using this code which I found here on stackoverflow but it only saves the first select.

```
$(function() {
  if($.cookie('remember_select') != null) {
    $('.select_class option[value="' + $.cookie('remember_select') + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
  $('.select_class').change(function() {
    $.cookie('remember_select', $('.select_class option:selected').val(), {expires: 365, path: '/'});
  });
});
```

Thanks

Here is the working soltuion I came up with...

```
<select class="select_class" id="foo" name="foo">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

$(function(){                                                                                      
    var selectbox=$('#setup').find('.select_class'), selectboxCookieName='selection';
        selectbox.each(function(){
        $(this).prop('value', $.cookie(selectboxCookieName + '|' + this.name));
    });

    selectbox.change(function(){
        if(this.value){
            $.cookie(selectboxCookieName + '|' + this.name, this.value,{
                expires: 365
            });
        }else{
            $.removeCookie(selectboxCookieName + '|' + this.name);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case value of cookie will be overridden with every change in certain select element. You need to modify the cookie saving, so that you can distinguish between different elements. e.g.: save in the same cookie the list of value per every control {"element1":"option 1", "elementX":"optionY"}, something like:

```
var controlId =  $('.select_class).attr("id"); //assume id is elementX
var controlValue = $('.select_class option:selected').val(); //assume value is optionX
var oldValue = $.parseJSON($.cookie('remember_select'));
var data = {};
data[controlId] = controlValue; //now data is {"elementX":"optionX"}
var newValue = $.extend({}, oldValue, data); //add or replace the value for elementX 
$.cookie('remember_select', JSON.stringify(newValue), {expires: 365, path: '/'});
```

Now you need to update appropriate code to retrieve value for certain control, something like:

```
var data = $.parseJSON($.cookie('remember_select')); // json object
var controlValue = data[controlId];
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and your reply Borys but unfortunetly for me I don't understand your code, it's a little more complicated then my knowledge of all this goes. I will keep playing with it and see what I can learn.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I figured out...

```
<select class="select_class" id="foo" name="foo">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

$(function(){                                                                                      
  var selectbox=$('#setup').find('.select_class'), selectboxCookieName='selection';
  selectbox.each(function(){
    $(this).prop('value', $.cookie(selectboxCookieName + '|' + this.name));
  });

  selectbox.change(function(){
    if(this.value){
        $.cookie(selectboxCookieName + '|' + this.name, this.value,{
            expires: 365
        });
    }else{
        $.removeCookie(selectboxCookieName + '|' + this.name);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Beware that you create a cookie for every select element, but number of cookies is limited per browser and for instance for Internet Explorer depending on its version  is in average about 20 cookies per domain name

Comment: Thanks for the info Borys I didn't know that. For now this works for my needs but I'll try and come up with a more elaborate solution in the future. :)